# How to pass parameter to delegate function from ajax callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm developing a prototype in `jQuery` for using `ajax` call simpler.

**Code**

```
 ajax: {
    call : function(url,dataToSend,doOnSuccess,doOnFailure) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: dataToSend
            ,
            //cache: false,
            success: function (result) {                 

                    doOnSuccess();

            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorText) {

                    doOnFailure();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**prototype**

```
ajax.call("MyUrl",{data:"MyData To Send"},alert(),alert());
```

For example I want to show result of success in alert.
So how can I pass ajax callbacks parameters to My delegates(e.g doOnSuccess() and doOnFailure()) which I passed as parameter?

Best regards!!

Comment: Please add the right tags to the question

Comment: How is your prototype simpler than `$.post(url, params).done(onDone).fail(onFail)`? It seems just a redundant wrapper to me ^^

Comment: @moonwave99 : see?! I want to be able to pass callback parameter to functions which pass to callbacks : in your example I want to pass xhr to onFail function which you are passing, got it?

Comment: @EhsanShirvan it is already passed. If you want to insist on your way, just call `doOnFailure(xhr)`, and list `xhr` as a function argument in your callback.

Answer (score 0):

if return callback Ajax read `when or deferred` in jquery:

[jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

[jQuery.deferred](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)

Or
Call function e.g:

```
ajax.call("MyUrl",{data:"MyData To Send"},alert,alert);
```

Comment: sometimes the function which I pass as delegate to ajax callback own some parameters , so when calling them in callbacks I want ti pass some extra parameters to them :

Comment: simple: remove () in call function 'ajax.call("MyUrl",{data:"MyData To Send"},alert,alert);'

Comment: please test 'var ajax= {
  call :function call(doOnFailure){
                        doOnFailure();
  }
};
ajax.call(alert)'

Answer (score 0):

Ajax or not, this is a matter of callback functions in js.
You just have to pass the functions as parameters. Lets define your custom doOnSuccess and doOnFailure functions:

```
function doOnSuccess(data, textStatus, xhr){
    /* Do something with data, textStatus, xhr */
    alert(data);
}

function doOnFailure(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    /* Do something with parameters) */
    alert('error');
}
```

Then you can define your ajax function:

```
 ajax: {
    call : function(url,dataToSend,doOnSuccess,doOnFailure) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: dataToSend
            ,
            //cache: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {                 
                    /* Do something with data before doOnSuccess */
                    doOnSuccess(data, textStatus, xhr);

            },
            error: doOnFailure
        });

    }
}
```

Now we can call the ajax function:

```
ajax.call("MyUrl",{data:"MyData To Send"},doOnSuccess,doOnFailure);
```

Comment: `success: doOnSuccess` would be enough, w/o the anonymous wrapper. Then the OP would realise that the whole thing becomes superfluous eventually : ))

Comment: You're right. wanted to add the option to manipulate data before the invokation.